# Self update for tkinter project in python 2.7 loops forever?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I have searched and applied several of the suggestion on stack before posting this. None have worked, but the code below is the closest I have come to it working.

What I want to accomplish is to build a small GUI that monitors several servers' CPU, processes (currently the command is just `ls`), and CRON status. Everything works fine except for a feature where the application automatically updates. I already have an update button, and would like to be able to call the function `refresh()` that the button is attached to every minute.

I am new to tkinter and have some doubts about other practices that I have written into the program. If you see anything alarming please feel free to say something.

I currently receive no error, but the program loops forever with no planned delay.

Thanks in advance!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import ttk, os, subprocess, datetime
import ConfigParser
from Tkinter import *

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read("p_watch.ini")



def main():
    root = Tk()
    root.title('Processor Watch')
    root.geometry('800x480')
    app = ProcessorWatch(root)
    root.mainloop()
    root.destroy()



def ConfigSectionMap(section):
    config_dict = {}
    options = config.options(section)
    for option in options:
        try:
            config_dict[option] = config.get(section, option)
            if config_dict[option] == -1:
                DebugPrint("skip: %s" % option)
        except:
            print("exception on %s!" % option)
            config_dict[option] = None
    return config_dict



class ProcessorWatch:

    def __init__(self, master):

        ### create tabs for different machines
        notebook = ttk.Notebook(master)
        notebook.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        frame1 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        frame1.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        frame2 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        frame2.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        frame3 = ttk.Frame(notebook)
        frame3.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
        notebook.add(frame1, text='Processor1')
        notebook.add(frame2, text='Processor2')
        notebook.add(frame3, text='Processor3')
        notebook.grid(sticky = 'NSEW')

        frame1_creds = ConfigSectionMap('processor 1')
        frame2_creds = ConfigSectionMap('processor 2')
        frame3_creds = ConfigSectionMap('processor 3')

        frame1.host_string  = frame1_creds['user'] + '@' + frame1_creds['host']
        frame1.index        = 0
        frame2.host_string  = frame2_creds['user'] + '@' + frame1_creds['host']
        frame2.index        = 1
        frame3.host_string  = frame3_creds['user'] + '@' + frame1_creds['host']
        frame3.index        = 2
        frames = [frame1,frame2,frame3]

        self.cron_button = {}
        self.spinbox = {}
        self.refresh_num = {}
        self.cpu_usage = {}
        self.cpu_label = {}
        self.usage_label = {}
        self.quit_button = {}
        self.refresh_button = {}


        for frame in frames:

            master.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
            master.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

            process_count = 0

            ### execute terminal commands
            self.cpu_usage[frame.index] = os.popen(
                "ssh -t " + frame.host_string + " grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage \"%\"}'"
                ).read()
            grep_results = os.popen("ls")
            cron_activity = os.popen("ssh -t " + frame.host_string + " \'service cron status | grep Active\'").read()

            ### determine and display CRON activity
            if 'inactive (dead)' in cron_activity:
                self.cron_button[frame.index] = Button(frame, text='CRON (inactive)',fg='white',bg='red', command= lambda f=frame: self.start_cron(master,f))
                self.cron_button[frame.index].grid(padx=20, ipady=15, pady=3,row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')
            else :
                self.cron_button[frame.index] = Button(frame, text='CRON (active)',fg='white',bg='green', command= lambda f=frame: self.stop_cron(master,f))
                self.cron_button[frame.index].grid(padx=20, ipady=15, pady=3,row=0, column=0, sticky='EW')

            ### config and display CPU usage
            self.usage_label[frame.index] = Label(frame, text='CPU Usage \n' + str(self.cpu_usage[frame.index].rstrip()),fg='white',bg='red')
            self.usage_label[frame.index].grid(padx=20, ipady=10, pady=3,row=3, column=0, sticky='EW')

            ### set up buttons
            self.quit_button[frame.index] = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red",  command=frame.quit)
            self.quit_button[frame.index].grid(padx=120, pady=60,row=6, column=0)
            self.refresh_button[frame.index] = Button(frame, text="REFRESH", fg="blue", command= lambda f=frame: self.refresh(master,f))
            self.refresh_button[frame.index].grid(padx=20, pady=3,row=5, column=0, sticky='EW')

            ### populate listbox
            self.listbox = Listbox(frame, height=28, width=60)
            self.scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=self.listbox.yview)
            self.listbox['yscrollcommand'] = self.scrollbar.set
            for line in grep_results:
                self.listbox.insert('end', str(line).rstrip())
                process_count+=1
            self.scrollbar.grid(row = 0, column = 4, sticky='NSE', rowspan=8)
            self.listbox.grid(row = 0, column = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky='E', rowspan=8)

            ### config and display number of processes running
            self.count_label = Label(frame, text='Perl Processes \n' + str(process_count),fg='black',bg='grey').grid(padx=20, ipady=10, pady=3,row=1, column=0, sticky='EW')
            self.refresh_label = Label(frame, text='Last Refresh at ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ,fg='black').grid(padx=0, ipady=0, pady=0,row=7, column=0, sticky='EW')

        self.update(master,frame)


    def refresh(self,master,frame):
        # if self.usage_label[frame.index] is not None:
        #     self.usage_label[frame.index].destroy()
        ### execute terminal commands
        self.cpu_usage[frame.index] = os.popen(
                "ssh -t " + frame.host_string + " grep 'cpu ' /proc/stat | awk '{usage=($2+$4)*100/($2+$4+$5)} END {print usage \"%\"}'"
                ).read()
        self.usage_label[frame.index].configure(text='CPU Usage \n' + str(self.cpu_usage[frame.index].rstrip()))
        grep_results = os.popen("ls")
        # grep_results = os.popen("ps aux | grep \"\.pl\" | grep -invertmatch grep")
        cron_activity = os.popen("ssh -t " + frame.host_string + " \'service cron status | grep Active\'").read()
        process_count = 0
        self.listbox.delete(0, END)
        # for line in grep_results:
        #     print line
        #     self.listbox.insert('end', str(line).rstrip())
        #     process_count+=1
        # self.listbox.grid(row = 0, column = 2, columnspan = 2, sticky='E', rowspan=8)
        self.count_label = Label(frame, text='Perl Processes \n' + str(process_count),fg='black',bg='grey').grid(padx=20, ipady=10, pady=3,row=1, column=0, sticky='EW')
        self.refresh_label = Label(frame, text='Last Refresh at ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') ,fg='black').grid(padx=0, ipady=0, pady=0,row=7, column=0, sticky='EW')



    # starting and stopping cron requires a password unless the user is configured not to
    def start_cron(self,master,frame):
        print "Starting Cron On " + frame.host_string
        try:
            os.system("ssh -t " + frame.host_string + " \'sudo service cron start\'")
            print "Cron Successfully Started On " + frame.host_string
            cron_activity = os.popen("ssh -t " + frame.host_string + " \'service cron status | grep Active\'").read()
            if 'active (running)' in cron_activity:
                self.cron_button[frame.index].configure(text='CRON (active)')
                self.cron_button[frame.index].configure(bg='green')
                self.cron_button[frame.index].configure(command= lambda: self.stop_cron(master,frame))
                master.update()
        except:
            print "Cron Failed On " + frame.host_string



    # starting and stopping cron requires a password unless the user is configured not to
    def stop_cron(self,master,frame):
        print "Stopping Cron On " + frame.host_string
        try:
            os.system("ssh -t " + frame.host_string + " \'sudo service cron stop\'")
            print "Cron Successfully Stopped On " + frame.host_string
            cron_activity = os.popen("ssh -t " + frame.host_string + " \'service cron status | grep Active\'").read()
            if 'inactive (dead)' in cron_activity:
                self.cron_button[frame.index].configure(text='CRON (inactive)')
                self.cron_button[frame.index].configure(bg='red')
                self.cron_button[frame.index].configure(command= lambda: self.start_cron(master,frame))
                master.update()
        except: 
            print "Cron Failed On " + frame.host_string



    def update(self,master,frame):
        # While the pipe has data, read and update the StringVar
        self.refresh(master,frame)

        # set the update method to run again in 1 seconds time
        master.after(60000,self.update(master,frame))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic algorithm for running something periodically looks like this:

```
def refresh(root):
    <do whatever you want here>
    root.after(60000, refresh, root)
```

When you call this function once, it will do whatever you want, then schedule itself to be called again in one minute.

You need to make sure that `<do whatever you want here>` takes only a few hundred milliseconds. Otherwise your application will get laggy, or freeze.

The mistake you made in your code is here:

```
master.after(60000,self.update(master,frame))
```

This is identical to the following:

```
result = self.update(master, frame)
master.after(60000, result)
```

The important thing to remember is that `after` requires a *callable* as the first argument after the number of milliseconds. If that callable needs arguments, they can be appended as additional arguments.

Comment: Thanks @bryan-oakley. This definitely taught me something and sparked another round of googleing and trial and error. I think there may be something more fundamentally wrong with the entire program unless I am not understanding something correctly. When I try to use root (or in my case self), as in your example, I get the error `AttributeError: ProcessorWatch instance has no attribute 'after'`. But when I try to execute `master.update()` instead of `self.update()` there is no error, but `update()` does not seem to be called. Am I initializing ProcessorWatch incorrectly?

Comment: @ThomasCannon `after` is a method available to every  widget. My example simply requires that you pass _any_ widget to it. In your case, `self` is not a widget, hence the error.

Comment: Ah! That clarifies a lot. Thank you!